# Tab Bar issues with iphone x simulator

Tags: ios, autolayout, uitabbar, iphone-x

So recently I am having issues with the tab bar icons moving out of position on the iphone x simulator. The iphone se,8,and 8 plus work fine but on the iphone x the icons move as shown in the picture below. Any help or input would be greatly appreciated thank you in advance.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4x9c9.png]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XaNL8.png]

Comment: Can you post your codes or storyboard which shows how do you implement the tabbar?

Comment: did you find any solution for it?????

Comment: Sadly not yet. Also we have not tested with an actual iphone x so we are unsure if the issue is pertaining to the simulator or not

Answer (score 1):

We ended up finding the solution. We had a custom tab bar height set and it was conflicting with the iphone x screen size. We created a safety by making an if else statement to change the tab bar height to an appropriate height based off of the screen height if the phone was an iphone x.

Also to solve the problem of black bars showing up between the View controller and the tab bar, we just clicked the extend under bottom bar option on the storyboard for each respective view controller